# What is the additional information inside a HTML tag called for web scraping identification

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am messing around with web scraping and I am a beginner. I am working on a web scraping tool and I am trying to get the value of a piece of information inside a HTML tag.

Here is an example;

```
<a href="tel:+1-860-351-9131" id="dealer-phone-e048470c-570f-4a26-841c-b4c258a3298e" class="sds-button--secondary contact-by-phone" phx-hook="CallSourceDniSRPCallButton" phx-update="ignore" data-linkname="dealer-phone-srp" data-activity-rule-type="custom" data-index="1" data-call-intent-id="srp-call-intent" data-listing-id="e048470c-570f-4a26-841c-b4c258a3298e" data-make="Volkswagen" data-model="Taos" data-phone-number="8603519131" data-trim="1.5T SE" data-year="2023" data-vin="3VVNX7B25PM316320">Call</a>
```

This example has Class's - ID's and then a bunch of sub "class-Id's" which I am not sure the correct name of.

I am trying to scrape the data from data-vin in this example and get the vin number of this vehicle but i dont know what the additional class/id's are called to begin to look up how I can try and get this information

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you try to get the [`elements`/`tags`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) and their `values` - [`attrs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) will provide them as `dict`:

```
soup.a.attrs
```

To pick an `attribute` simply call `.get('ATTRIBUTE_NAME')`:

```
soup.a.get('href')
```

or if you like to get all `data-*` filter your `dict`:

```
{k:soup.a.attrs[k] for k in soup.a.attrs if k.startswith('data')}
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<a href="tel:+1-860-351-9131" id="dealer-phone-e048470c-570f-4a26-841c-b4c258a3298e" class="sds-button--secondary contact-by-phone" phx-hook="CallSourceDniSRPCallButton" phx-update="ignore" data-linkname="dealer-phone-srp" data-activity-rule-type="custom" data-index="1" data-call-intent-id="srp-call-intent" data-listing-id="e048470c-570f-4a26-841c-b4c258a3298e" data-make="Volkswagen" data-model="Taos" data-phone-number="8603519131" data-trim="1.5T SE" data-year="2023" data-vin="3VVNX7B25PM316320">Call</a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.a.attrs
```

##### Output

```
{'href': 'tel:+1-860-351-9131',
 'id': 'dealer-phone-e048470c-570f-4a26-841c-b4c258a3298e',
 'class': ['sds-button--secondary', 'contact-by-phone'],
 'phx-hook': 'CallSourceDniSRPCallButton',
 'phx-update': 'ignore',
 'data-linkname': 'dealer-phone-srp',
 'data-activity-rule-type': 'custom',
 'data-index': '1',
 'data-call-intent-id': 'srp-call-intent',
 'data-listing-id': 'e048470c-570f-4a26-841c-b4c258a3298e',
 'data-make': 'Volkswagen',
 'data-model': 'Taos',
 'data-phone-number': '8603519131',
 'data-trim': '1.5T SE',
 'data-year': '2023',
 'data-vin': '3VVNX7B25PM316320'}
```